# Google Script / JavaScript: Missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm currently working on trying to automate deletion of security video files after they are past 30 days old for my own home security project. When I try running the script, 
I get a "Missing ) after argument list" for line 67 which is

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
            'modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDateAsString + '" and (name contains 'Driveway' or name contains 'Kitchen' or name contains 'FrontDoor')');
```

I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong as I did follow the example that the Google Documentation stated for compound clauses:

```
modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00' and (mimeType contains 'image/' or mimeType contains 'video/')
```

I looked at similar questions that were asked but I'm not sure if they applied to mine so I decided to ask my own here.

Here is my script for reference:

```
function getFilesByDate() {
      var arrayOfFileIDs = [];

      var ThirtyDaysBeforeNow = new Date().getTime()-3600*1000*24*30;
        // 30 is the number of days 
        //(3600 seconds = 1 hour, 1000 milliseconds = 1 second, 24 hours = 1 day and 30 days is the duration you wanted
        //needed in yr-month-day format

      var cutOffDate = new Date(ThirtyDaysBeforeNow);
      var cutOffDateAsString = Utilities.formatDate(cutOffDate, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
      Logger.log(cutOffDateAsString);

      var theFileID = "";

      //Create an array of file ID's by date criteria
      var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
        'modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDateAsString + '" and (name contains 'Driveway' or name contains 'Kitchen' or name contains 'FrontDoor')');
      //This is LINE 67

      while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        theFileID = file.getId();

        arrayOfFileIDs.push(theFileID);
        Logger.log('theFileID: ' + theFileID);
        Logger.log('date last updated: ' + file.getLastUpdated());
      }

      return arrayOfFileIDs;
      Logger.log('arrayOfFileIDs: ' + arrayOfFileIDs);

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your quotes. Replace this:

```
'" and (name contains 'Driveway' or name contains 'Kitchen' or name contains 'FrontDoor')'
```

with this:

```
'" and (name contains \'Driveway\' or name contains \'Kitchen\' or name contains \'FrontDoor\')'
```

because right now, your String looks like this to JS:

```
modifiedTime > "2016-08-15T12:03:54" and (name contains
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can't believe I miss checking for proper quoting.